# if statements and time php

Tags: php

The user enters a time to hire a bus and the length of hours. I then query this information from mysql database. I find the end time of the hire and figure out how many hours after midnight the hire is for, if any. I'm pretty sure I had this working but now it just isn't working and I cannot see why it won't. Finding the end time is right but my if statement doesn't seem to work. For example, when the end time is "02:00:00" so 2am, it follows the path of the if statement so that the time after midnight is 3 hours, when it should be 2 hours. Any help as to why? Thanks.
($hireid = latest hireid in database)

```
//GET LATEST TIME AND LENGTH OF HIRE

$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, length FROM hire WHERE hireid='$hireid'") or   die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$time = $row['time'];
$length = $row['length'];

}
//FIND AMOUNT OF HOURS BEFORE AND AFTER MIDNIGHT  

echo "Time: " . $time . "</br>";
echo "Length: " . $length . "</br>";
echo "Hours: " . $hours . "</br>";

echo "End time: " . $endtime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($time . '+ ' . $length .  'hours')) . "</br>";

$hoursafter = 0;

if ($endtime = "01:00:00") {
$hoursafter = 1;
}

if ($endtime = "02:00:00") {
$hoursafter = 2;
}

if ($endtime = "03:00:00") {
$hoursafter = 3;
}


echo "Hours after midnight: " . $hoursafter . "</br>";
```

Comment: Hi - this is not a great way of doing this, use date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to pull out the info you want from the date object and eg (hour) then you don't need to match against a string.  What does `echo $endtime` give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do:

```
if ($endtime == '02:00:00'){
$hoursafter = 2;
}
```

You just mis one = in your if statement. If you change this by all your statements in the script and it will work :)

Comment: hmm, now all endtimes past midnight just equal 0 :c

Comment: Then there is something wrong in the begin. Your while is also not wat you will espect i guess because it only will show the last record if you have more than one record. If you only espect one record just use


     `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: ive been testing the code without using the database and just giving the time and length variables certain times and lengths, still coming out as aftermidnight = 0 when it should be 1, 2 or 3

Comment: I know why that is, because you count the actual time plus the hours. so if it is now 20:00:00 and you add 3 hours that will be 23:00:00. we need to change the if statement to this:
`if ($endtime >= "01:00:00" && $endtime <= '01:59:59') {
$hoursafter = 1;
}

if ($endtime >= "02:00:00" && $endtime <= '02:59:59') {
$hoursafter = 2;
}

if ($endtime > "03:00:00") {
$hoursafter = 3;
}`